# Incorrect mime-type from PHP

Tags: php, apache

When uploading a Power Point 2000 document (.ppt) created in Microsoft Power Point it is a returning a mime type of application/vnd.ms-office. I would expect application/vnd.ms-powerpoint to come back from:

```
    <?php
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime_type = $finfo->file($filepath);

    // strip off the mime encoding information
    $mime_type = substr($mime_type, 0, strpos($mime_type, ';'));
```

Any ideas why this maybe the case?

I am running the following:

- Ubuntu
- PHP 5.2
- Apache 2

Comment: `finfo` relies on the underlying system's `file` functionality so you'll probably have to investigate there. Maybe update the `mime_magic` file....

Comment: I can't see any mime types in there of application/vnd.ms-office however so I am still unsure where it is coming from. I have checked the mime_magic file in Apache and the main system one. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finfo` ins't 100% reliable, especially when it comes to Microsoft Office documents. I don't think there is an easy fix to your solution. You might try, if it returns `application/vnd.ms-office`, then additionally check if the extension of the file is `.ppt`, and if it is, set the mime type to `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`. Of course an extension is meaningless, but those using Microsoft, there is a good chance a file with extension `.ppt` is a powerpoint and not anything else.

Comment: I have a file which maps mime types in my application so I can always get the same pretty name such as Powerpoint for file mime types. So I have just temporarily made `application/vnd.ms-office` a mime mapping for Powerpoint to stop the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Apache MIME types file has the correct MIME type for that file extention. You'll want to look at `/conf/mime.types` and add these lines if they don't exist.

```
application/vnd.powerpoint ppt
application/vnd.powerpoint pptx
```

You will need to restart Apache after making these changes.

Comment: These lines do both exist currently in `/etc/mime.types` there is no mime.types file in the Apache conf directories. `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint ppt pps` and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx`