# doc file from libreoffice does not give extension information?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to get extension of uploaded file by

```
$file->guessExtension();
```

and getting the empty value but mime type is showing

```
application/vnd.ms-office
```

File is created in libre office inside linux environment named **newFile.doc**.

**Edit 1** I need to know only that why guessExtension is giving empty value?
           By calling extension function, I should get doc string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question isn't directly related to Symfony2. It seems like an issue with PHP and Apache MIME types configuration.

Take a look at these answers:

[MSOFFICE MIME type verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214720/msoffice-mime-type-verification)

[Incorrect mime-type from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607120/incorrect-mime-type-from-php)

Comment: My question is not pointing toward mime type, Actually i am having problem with guessExtension function inside symfony.

Comment: Then you shouldn´t use `guessExtension()` as it returns the extension based on the mime type as opposed to `getExtension()`, which returns the extension of the file. Take a look: http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html